# conexión de swi prolog con php utilizando xampp

Tags: php, xampp, prolog, swi-prolog

al realizar  el siguiente procedimiento.

- ingresar a CMD.
- digitar la instrucción:

  ```
  cd C:\xampp\htdocs\ConexionPhp
  ```
- ubicación de la carpeta de proyecto.
- Una vez dentro de la carpeta que abre CMD,coloco la instrucción:

  ```
   swipl -s ejemplo.pl -g "test." -t halt.
  ```

obtengo como resultado:

> "swipl" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o
>   archivo por lotes ejecutable.

y cuando ejecuto el proyecto el `localhost:8080`, obtengo **NULL**.

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de instalar swi-prolog es cuando te pregunta si quieres poner los programas en el PATH, que no es otra cosa que agregar la carpeta

```
C:\Program Files\swipl
```

a la variable de sistema `PATH`.

Si se te olvidó no hay problema, pues solamente debes agregar esa carpeta a la variable

[image: edición de variable de ambiente en windows]